# Android app Takes too Long to Load

Tags: android, performance, lazy-loading, android-multidex

I have android application with activities and fragments. It also included firebase and GoogleMaps.

After building and running application on my Nexus 5 Device, app activity takes too long to load.

I am trying to trace by making check for the time lags and remove many lags in pre-load. But I didn't get full success.

**Error Logs**

```
09-26 20:31:41.777 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ru.ex.mike.clickauto-1/lib/arm
09-26 20:31:41.785 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
09-26 20:31:41.785 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/MultiDex: install
09-26 20:31:41.785 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
09-26 20:31:41.813 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-26 20:31:41.819 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-26 20:31:41.819 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto D/FirebaseApp: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-26 20:31:41.819 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-26 20:31:41.843 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-26 20:31:41.972 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
09-26 20:31:42.049 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000a/n/armeabi-v7a
09-26 20:31:42.049 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000a/n/armeabi
09-26 20:31:42.123 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 9683000
09-26 20:31:42.130 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9683438
09-26 20:31:42.338 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/c: Token loaded from file. Expires in: 350346286 ms.
09-26 20:31:42.338 27062-27062/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/c: Scheduling next attempt in 350046 seconds.
09-26 20:31:42.517 27062-27183/ru.ex.mike.clickauto D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-26 20:31:42.545 27062-27116/ru.ex.mike.clickauto W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.HardwareRenderer android.view.View$AttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer' on a null object reference
                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:504)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1104)
                                                                  at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:560)
                                                                  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-26 20:31:42.657 27062-27183/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
09-26 20:31:42.660 27062-27183/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-26 20:31:43.125 27062-27072/ru.ex.mike.clickauto W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.136ms
09-26 20:31:43.142 27062-27072/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15095(843KB) AllocSpace objects, 26(3MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 36MB/36MB, paused 14.746ms total 33.657ms
09-26 20:31:44.528 27062-27175/ru.ex.mike.clickauto W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
09-26 20:31:44.578 27062-27175/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
09-26 20:31:44.578 27062-27175/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
09-26 20:31:44.586 27062-27072/ru.ex.mike.clickauto I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10469(440KB) AllocSpace objects, 14(15MB) LOS objects, 33% free, 31MB/47MB, paused 2.467ms total 106.170ms
09-26 20:31:44.588 27062-27175/ru.ex.mike.clickauto W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000009/n/armeabi
09-26 20:31:44.599 27062-27175/ru.ex.mike.clickauto D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
09-26 20:31:44.679 27062-27175/ru.ex.mike.clickauto D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 172 Google release certificates
09-26 20:31:44.687 27062-27175/ru.ex.mike.clickauto D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 336 Google certificates
```

My question is: how remove more actions, that is take loading seconds

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: you are debugging or using the apk?

Comment: can you add code?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley debugging. And I have one more qstion: if i be using the apk (release), what loading speed changings?

Comment: @StefanoM5 what code? AndroidManifest or Activity or other?

Comment: debugging always waste a lot of time. in my old pc it uses 5 minutes for build-compiling. Once you release the apk the time wil change don't worry. try going in the project folder, find the apk file, send it to the phone and install it. you will see that the start time will be nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your app will always run slower on emulator.or while debugging.realase yur app.install on a real device and you will b fine.hope this helps

Comment: I run debug buid on real device Nexus 5 ( BrightRed :3 ) on Android 6. How I understood, in case of installation of release build in my device, lags (which happen because of mode debug) will improve?

Comment: Debugging involves execution of the code plus report of failure to the debugger.Therefore the lag experienced during debug will surely improve on release.Debugging on a real device will significantly improve lags.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when i run my app on emulator , every time white screen shows before splash screen. but after publish on play store. this problem finish.